# Difference between cross-validation functions in caret package

Tags: r

Suppose we have 3 models `M1, M2, M3`. We want to compare the performance of these models using 10 fold, 10 repeated cross-validation on a train set.

What is the difference between:

```
CV_Folds <- createMultiFolds(y, k = 10, times = 10)
fitControl <- trainControl(method='repeatedCV',index=CV_Folds))
```

and

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method= "repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=10)
```

Comment: Do they return different results? Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I've been messing with that myself and I see no difference. Specifying `index = CV_folds` simply streamlines things a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

The method `repeatedCV` is not a valid option.  A method of that name does not appear in the `caret` source code as of `6.0-34`.